# Convert image to png and then again to original type - Laravel, PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, image-conversion

I am using image intervention in laravel to upload and convert image(jpg, bmp, gif) to PNG type, after upload png image can be sent to another user. User who receives image will then convert that PNG image to original uploaded type back.

For example I am uploading JPG image which have size of 1.5MB, after upload and conversion to PNG it have size of 5MB. When user who received that png image converts it back to original JPG type, after conversion JPG image have size of 850KB (instead of 1.5MB). Problem is that when image is converted back to her original type, sizes are not the same. Is there a way to convert image and to get same size before conversion to png?

**1.5MB(JPG) -> PNG -> 850KB??(JPG)**

conversion to png:
    $png_image = (string) Img::make($image)->encode('png');

conversion back to original type:
    $originalImage = (string) Img::make($png_image_path)->encode($extension, 100);

Comment: My first question would be why are you doing this, why not just send the image in its original format?  The reason you are seeing this size difference with jpeg is because jpeg compression is a lossy file format, meaning each time you convert to jpeg you lose quality (information/bits).  Png is lossless, so in your code you are converting from a lossy format, to lossless and then back to lossy meaning you are losing more information.

Comment: I re-read my comment and realized that I didn't directly answer this question - "Is there a way to convert image and to get same size before conversion to png?"  The answer to that is, in the case of jpeg, no, you cannot. (Note: there are [lossless jpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG) formats such as jpeg 2000, but I am making the assumption that your jpegs are the standard lossy format).

Comment: Thanks for answer, then I will leave it as it is.